# Ajax request call to external api is returning [Object object]

Tags: ajax, api

I want to display the content from the API endpoint. It's the address of the company on their site

But I am getting [object object ]

I have tried and change my code several times but noy luck

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
                    url: 'http://datarecapture.premiumpension.com:8089/api/ContactUs/Contact', 
                    data: JSON.stringify(), // our data object
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    dataType: "json",
                     success: function (result)  {
                    // console log data to the console so we can see
                     alert("Success " + result);
                  },
                // here we will handle errors and validation messages
                  error: function (ErrorMessage) 
                  {  //debugger
                      alert("Error Message " + ErrorMessage);
                    }
                })
            })
```

Comment: The `alert` function does not handle objects...you would see the object in your console if you switched it to `console.log(result)` or `console.log('SUCCESS', result)`

Comment: I am still getting `Success [object Object]` on the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try

```
console.log(result)
```

most prboably in alert if data is coming

```
result.data
```

will work.

Please check how data is coming in console first

Comment: When I used `result.data` I am getting `Success undefined`

Comment: what is the result showing Console for this console.log(result)

Comment: Success [object Object]